# R (Error): x argument is missing, with no default

Tags: r, algorithm, function, loops, optimization

I am working with R.

I have some data ("train_data") below:

```
# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)

#view data
head(train_data)
         a1        b1  c1
1 110.36832  90.66670 662
2  96.28321 102.68244 810
3 101.95640  98.17639 956
4 121.58001  93.04896 697
5  95.08541 104.64527 712
```

In this example, I am interested in performing an arbitrary task:

1. Choose 7 random numbers (`"random_1"` (between 80 and 120), `"random_2"` (between "random_1" and 120) , `"random_3"` (between 85 and 120), `"random_4"` (between random_2 and 120), `"split_1"` (between 0 and 1), `"split_2"` (between 0 and 1), `"split_3"` (between 0 and 1 ))
2. Using these random numbers, perform a series of data manipulation procedures on "train_data" (these data manipulation procedures will be defined in the function below). For a specific set of 7 numbers, these data manipulation procedures will calculate a "total" mean.
3. Repeat steps 1) and 2) and see if you can find the set of these 7 numbers that produce the biggest value of the "total" mean.

Thus, I am trying to perform an optimization task.

Earlier, I was able to solve this task using a "random search":

```
# code for random search
results_table <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:10 ) {
    
    #generate random numbers
    random_1 =  runif(1, 80, 120)
    random_2 =  runif(1, random_1, 120)
    random_3 =  runif(1, 85, 120)
    random_4 =  runif(1, random_3, 120)
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    
    #calculate random quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    
    #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                   group_by(cat) %>%
                                   summarize(
                                       mean = mean(diff)
                                   ))
    
    #add "total mean" to this table
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))
    
    #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
    final_table_2$random_1 = random_1
    
    final_table_2$random_2 = random_2
    
    final_table_2$random_3 = random_3
    
    final_table_2$random_4 = random_4
    
    final_table_2$split_1 = split_1
    
    final_table_2$split_2 = split_2
    
    final_table_2$split_3 = split_3
    
    final_table_2$iteration_number = i
    
    
    results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)
    
    final_results = dcast(setDT(results_table), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')

#keep 5 largest resuts
  final_results <- head(final_results[order(-total)], 5)
    
}
```

Now, we can view the results of the random search:

```
 #view results

final_results

   iteration_number  random_1 random_2  random_3  random_4    split_1   split_2   split_3         a         b         c total
1:                8 104.52182 104.8939  96.63609  99.14640 0.45389635 0.7970865 0.8264969 0.4560440 0.7954545 0.8265306 0.755
2:               10 119.04797 119.9907  93.13250  93.62925 0.27018809 0.5025505 0.6707737 0.2758621 0.5000000 0.6681465 0.632
3:                1 114.69535 117.7922 109.89274 116.39624 0.61857197 0.9609914 0.2661892 0.6180022 0.9615385 0.2702703 0.623
4:                6  85.64905 100.8127  94.02205 106.41212 0.00197946 0.7476889 0.1235777 0.2500000 0.7470588 0.1234568 0.442
5:                3 106.14908 119.7681  95.61753 100.73192 0.20678470 0.1787206 0.7166830 0.2111801 0.1802030 0.7146067 0.423
```

According to the above table (for a very small random search of 10 iterations), the combination of "`random_1, random_2, random_3, random_4, split_1, split_2, split_3`" = ( 104.52182 104.8939 96.63609 99.14640 0.45389635 0.7970865 0.8264969) produces the highest "total" of 0.755 .

**My Problem:** The "random search" is not a very effective way at solving this problem. I am trying to use a different optimization algorithm to try and identify a set of `random_1, random_2, random_3, random_4, split_1, split_2, split_3` that produces the biggest value of `total`.

From the following link (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html), I decided to follow the example for optimizing this problem using an optimization algorithm called the "genetic algorithm":

```
#example of the genetic algorithm

#load library
library(GA)

#define function
Rastrigin <- function(x1, x2)
{
  20 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x1) + cos(2*pi*x2))
}

x1 <- x2 <- seq(-5.12, 5.12, by = 0.1)
f <- outer(x1, x2, Rastrigin)

#run optimization algorithm
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness =  function(x) -Rastrigin(x[1], x[2]),
         lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), upper = c(5.12, 5.12), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)

#view results of the genetic algorithm (the answer that optimizes the function in this example is (x1 = 5.4 e-05, x2 = 6.400 e-05)
summary(GA)

              x1           x2
[1,] 5.41751e-05 6.400989e-05
```

I now want to apply the "genetic algorithm" to my problem. This requires the user to define a "fitness function" that formalizes the requirements and directions for the "genetic algorithm". For my problem, I defined the "fitness function" as follows:

```
#define fitness function
fitness <- function(random_1, random_2, random_3, random_4, split_1, split_2, split_3) {

    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
# calculate the total mean : this is what needs to be optimized
    mean = mean(final_table$diff)
    
    
}
```

Just to test that this function works:

```
#call function for a specific set of the 7 numbers 

 a = fitness(85, 100, 90, 110, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3)

# view the corresponding "total mean"
a
[1] 0.845
```

Now, I am trying to put everything together and instruct the "genetic algorithm" to optimize the "fitness function" I defined by considering different ranges of values for `"random_1, random_2, random_3, random_4, split_1, split_2, split_3"`

#genetic algorithm for my example:

```
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness =  fitness,
         lower = c(80, 80, 80, 80, 0,0,0), upper = c(120, 120, 120, 120, 1,1,1), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `cat`.
i `cat = ifelse(...)`.
x argument "random_3" is missing, with no default
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `cat`.
i `cat = ifelse(...)`.
x argument "random_3" is missing, with no default
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Does anyone know why this error is being produced? Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify your function differently in the `ga()` call.  By analogy with the example that works, you need...

```
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness = function(x)  fitness(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7]),
         lower = c(80, 80, 80, 80, 0,0,0), upper = c(120, 120, 120, 120, 1,1,1), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)
```

It seems that `fitness` needs to be a function of a single variable (in this case a 7-element vector), rather than a function of seven scalar values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I just had a question, when I view the summary of the GA function : "summary(GA)", I get the following results: GA results: 
Iterations             = 245 
Fitness function value = 0.996 
Solution = 
           x1       x2       x3       x4        x5        x6        x7
[1,] 95.42393 99.91848 89.19499 88.20783 0.6760711 0.4669005 0.4590385

Comment: But when I take this solution and manually place it into the fitness function, I get a different answer:  a = fitness(95.42393 ,99.91848, 89.19499 ,88.20783, 0.6760711 ,0.4669005 ,0.4590385)
> a
[1] 0.286

Comment: The result of the  "Fitness function value = 0.996 ", but when you manually enter the enter the 7 numbers that the GA provided, you get "0.286". Do you know the reason why these two numbers are different?

Comment: Last question: is it possible to know whether the following code:   "GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness = function(x)  fitness(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7]),
         lower = c(80, 80, 80, 80, 0,0,0), upper = c(120, 120, 120, 120, 1,1,1), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)" ... is this trying to find the "maximum value of the total mean", or is this finding the "minimum value of the total mean"? thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @stats555 Sorry - I'm not very familiar with the details of the GA output, so can't answer that off the top of my head.  The documentation for the GA package will probably help.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I will try to read it in more detail!

Comment: if you have time, can you please take a look at this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68275805/r-miscellaneous-errors-while-trying-to-plot-graphs thank you so much!

Comment: @stats555 I have just noticed that your fitness function produces answers that depend on random numbers. The values of `split` passed as arguments are overwritten by calls to `runif`. This explains why you don't get the same answer as the `summary`. I also wonder what it means to optimise such a function, and whether the answer you are getting is what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Andrew, just one more question - when executing the "GA" function, is it possible to add some constraints? For example : GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness = function(x)  fitness(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7]),
         lower = c(80, 80, 80, 80, 0,0,0), upper = c(120, 120, 120, 120, 1,1,1), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100) .... is it possible to specify that x[2] must be between "random_1" and 120?