# R Error: Contour plot only works with two dimensional functions

Tags: r, function, loops, optimization, data-visualization

I am working with R. I am learning about optimizing functions and how to visualize the results.

For instance, suppose I have some data and a function I am want to optimize.

Here is the data:

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)


# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
```

And here is the function:

```
library(optimization)

fitness <- function(x) {
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% 
        mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= x[1] & b1 <= x[3], "a", 
                            ifelse(a1 <= x[2] & b1 <= x[4], "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    
    x[5:7] <- prop.table(abs(x[5:7]))
    
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[5])))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[6])))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[7])))
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    # calculate the total mean : this is what needs to be optimized
    mean = mean(final_table$diff) 
}
```

Now, I run the optimization algorithm:

```
Output <- optim_nm(fitness, k = 7, trace = TRUE)
```

The documentation from the "optimization" package (e.g. https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/optimization/vignettes/vignette_master.pdf ) indicates that for 2 variables, you can visualize the results of the optimization. For example:

[image]

The "plot" function can be used to make the picture on the right, but of course only in 2 dimensions.

When you the run the "plot" command by itself, the following error is produced:

```
#plot
plot(Output, 'contour')

Error in plot.optim_nmsa(Output, "contour") : 
  Contour plot only works with two dimensional functions.
```

I tried to manually specify that this plot be made using only two variables, e.g

```
plot(Output[1], Output[2], 'contour')
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I tried the following command, but this resulted in a strange picture and a warning message:

```
 plot(train_data$a1, train_data$b1, 'contour')

Warning message:
In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) :
  plot type 'contour' will be truncated to first character
```

[image]

**Question** : Is there any way to get the "yellow contour" picture by just using two variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element from `Output` that contains `x_1` and `x_2` is `Output[[3]]`. I believe this is the one you want to plot (those are the names in the yellow plot).

You could then use:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1000)
# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)

Output <- optim_nm(fitness, k = 7, trace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(Output[[3]])

ggplot(df, aes(x = x_1, y = x_2, z = function_value))+
    geom_density_2d(binwidth = 0.005)+
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! If you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68275805/r-miscellaneous-errors-while-trying-to-plot-graphs? I am trying to use similar logic that you provided to solve this other question. Thank you so much!